# javascript one function for ajax request

Tags: javascript, function

as for now i have 97 same functions like this:

```
function member_requestDetail(member_id){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action.php',
    data: 'action=55&member_id='+member_id,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg){
            var Sresponse=eval('(' + msg + ')');
            if(Sresponse.status=='success'){
                detailWindow.innerHTML=Sresponse.memberDetails;
            }
            else{if(Sresponse.status=='error'){
                detailWindowError.innerHTML=Sresponse.errorText;
            }}
        }
        else{
            detailWindowError.innerHTML='Error';
        }
    }
});
}
```

i was wandering if i do something like this:

```
function requestAction(actionID,dataToSend,callback,error_callback){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action.php',
    data: 'action='+actionID+dataToSend,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg){
            var Sresponse=eval('(' + msg + ')');
            callback(Sresponse);
        }
        else{
            error_callback();
        }
    }
});
}
```

would it lose speed or something? do i have to do multithreading then or anything?
example if function **requestAction** gets multiple calls in a seccond.

hope someone understands!

thanks for help

Comment: You might want to reformat your question; some of the code is not formatted as a code block and is hard to read as a result.

Comment: Just few comments, javascript is not multi-threaded. Then `eval` may not be the best approach to read JSON, try `JSON.parse(msg)` instead.

Comment: Whenever you are tempted to use `eval`, think to yourself _"eval is **evil**"_. :) Seriously, there is almost no case where `eval` is appropriate.

Comment: OMG, 97 functions that do almost exactly the same! You should really refactor that/rethink your approach. And in addition to @Mic's comment: don't forget to include a library that can also parse JSON, like [json-sans-eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/): not all current browsers support `JSON.parse` natively.

Comment: there are much other things why i am using eval and not JSON.parse and btw. that wasnt part of my question ;) but thank you

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a noticeable performance impact to the approach you outlined, even if `requestAction()` gets multiple calls per second. You're only adding the overhead of one additional function call on the stack.

Comment: does it means then functions seccond call wont start untill first call is done? :(

Comment: @GreiglnYEG - do you know the answer to my comment? :(

Comment: Two calls to requestAction() are independent of each other. Note that different browsers have different characteristics regarding the number of threads available for Javascript, so you may only see one requestAction() call happening at a time. However, this would affect your current code in the same way.